# programmatically call Bootstrap validator

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqbootstrapvalidation

I have create my own **Bootstrap validator**:

```
$('.myValidatorClass').validator({          
    custom: {             
         'datainizio':function($el){
             return dataInizio($el);                         
         }             
    },
    errors: {
        datainizio: "error"
    }}).on('submit', function (e) {        
        // code                 
      }
    })
```

The method **dataInizio()** check if a "**start date**" field is filled when a "**end date**" field is filled; it works.

this is the **end date** field:

```
<input id="endDate" nama="endDate" data-datainizio="datainizio" />
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```

Now, I need to programmatically (I suppose) call the validator when the value of the "start date" field changes, in order to remove the errore message in the form.

I read this [page](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-events), and used `$("#form").validator('validate')`, but the error messages are not deleted on the page. It seems Bootstrap validator calls only its own "validation methods" and not also my "validation methods" like **datainizio**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Bootstrap Validation plugin and the jQuery Validate plugin are not the same thing.  Edited tags.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not clear to me. What you mean?

Comment: It's not an answer.  It's a comment.  I meant that you *incorrectly* tagged your question with the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 3):

use code bellow

```
$("#form")[0].checkValidity();
```

it return true false and simply check it out.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

if your form is coming dynamically ,so PLEASE use "jQuery" in place of "$"

```
jQuery('.myValidatorClass').validator({          
    custom: {             
         'datainizio':function(jQuery el){
             return dataInizio(jQuery el);                         
         }             
    },
    errors: {
        datainizio: "error"
    }}).on('submit', function (e) {        
        // code                 
      }
    })
```

Please let me know if see any issue :)